# problem building cpp project in eclipse

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, eclipse-cdt, msys

I have installed minGW and msys. In eclipse CDT I created c++ project that uses cross gcc toolchain.

Eclipse created make file which I can use through command line, so if I run `make all` project is correctly compiled, but if I use eclipse to build, it fails with following message

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project cpp ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chosen wrong toolchain in project, changed to mingw gcc and now it works